# Orbeon Forms - Loading Data from HTTP Service to Dropdown

Tags: rest, service, drop-down-menu, orbeon

I have an HTTP Service configured as below
[image: Capture1]
And the results of this service is as below[image: Capture2]
Then I have added an action to load these values coming in the keyword tag to a drop down(Priority) and the destination selection controls Item set is set as below
[image: Capture3]

But my drop down doesn't load items. Can someone please guide me in how to fill the item set in destination selection control? Below is the out put I get.
[image: Capture4]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XPath expressions you put in *Label* and *Value* are relative to the current item, which in your case is a `<keyword>`, so those expressions both need to be `.` (referring to the current node).

Comment: Excellent @n.path; I am glad this helped, and thanks for the update.